# How to use user profiles with MongoEngine (Django)?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, authentication, mongoengine

So, I'm trying to build up a simple site with a MongoDB database and Django (using MongoEngine), but I am stuck trying to understand how the user profiles work. I can save the mongo_auth.MongoUser document to the database just fine, but when it comes down to actually saving the profile, I'm not doing the right thing. Here is the User Profile model/document I am trying to setup with the MongoUser:

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from mongoengine import *

[...]

class UserProfile(Document):
    user = EmbeddedDocumentField('User')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

In Django with relational databases, the UserProfile was a models.Model and the user field was a OneToOne relationship, but I don't know how to map that with the MongoUser, so I guessed the following lines:

```
class UserProfile(Document):
    user = EmbeddedDocumentField('User')
```

But, apparently, it's not right since Django can't load the profile:

```
Unable to load the profile model, check AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in your project settings
```

I think my settings.py is configured correctly since I can save a MongoUser just fine (without a profile), and the following line tells Django where to find the UserProfile:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'comptes.UserProfile'
```

I am still new to Django and MongoDB, so all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must use mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField. Something like this

```
class UserProfile(Document):
     user = ReferenceField('User')
```

Comment: Thank you. Everything saves in the database, but the get_profile function still doesn't work (same error message). After digging up a bit in the mongoengine\django\auth.py file, I find that the function models.get_model('comptes', 'UserProfile') returns "None" when UserProfile is a document. Is that normal?